# Product of sequences in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Assume sequences $\{x_k\}$ and $\{y_k\}$ are in $\mathbb R^n$ and $x_k \to x$, $y_k \to y$.

1. Is it true that $x_k\cdot x_k \to x \cdot y$ ? Why or why not?

I think this one is false, but not quite sure how to prove it.

2. For $n = 3$. Is it true that $x_k \times x_k \to x \times y$ ? Why?

I have no idea about this one yet. Any saying will be helpful,

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you mean $x_k\cdot y_k \to x\cdot y$ and $x_k\times y_k\to x\times y.$

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach that works in any inner product space (replacing $x \cdot y$ with $\langle x, y\rangle$). Note that $\|x_n\| \leq M$ for some constant $M$ since $x_n$ converges. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
|x_n\cdot y_n - x\cdot y| &\leq |x_n\cdot y_n - x_n\cdot y| + |x_n\cdot y - x\cdot y|\tag{Triangle}\\
&= |x_n\cdot(y_n-y)| + |(x_n-x)\cdot y|\tag{Linearity}\\
&\leq \|x_n\|\,\|y_n-y\| + \|x_n-x\|\|y\|\tag{Cauchy-Schwarz}\\
&\leq M\|y_n-y\| + \|x_n-x\|\|y\|\to 0
\end{align*}
$$
so $x_n\cdot y_n \to x\cdot y$.

As far as the cross product goes, the argument that $x_n\times y_n \to x\times y$ is the same if we switch the Cauchy-Schwarz step with the fact that $\|x\times y\|= \|x\|\,\|y\|\sin\theta \leq \|x\|\|y\|$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

A sequence of vectors $x_k$ in $\mathbb R^n$ converges to $x$ if and only if all of its components converge to the respective components of $x.$